# SimpleAudioEngine stops playing sounds?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

For some reason, at first, simpleAudioEngine worked to play all sounds, but then, after a while, they stop working. I am using the simple audio engine to play sound effects that are under 1 second long and are all mp3s, while playing music using AVAudioPlayer. This is the code that I use for the simpleAudioEngine:

```cpp
//During initialization
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadeffect:@"jump.mp3"];
//When effect needs to be played
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playeffect:@"jump.mp3"];
```

Comment: Don't use mp3 for sfx, use wav or caf. Mp3 have to be decoded by the CPU because only one mp3 file can by decoded by the hardware decoder.

Comment: I have tried to use .wav files too, but for some reason they weren't working (and only those .wav files stopped, I had a few .aiff and an .mp3 that continued to work), so I converted them, but that didn't fix anything

Comment: wav/caf need to be mono - if they're stereo they won't play at all

Comment: change the file to 16bit, the wav files... maybe that helps. And also the preloadeffect remove it when using wav files. The wav its already uncompressed no need to preload.